# Speed up sleep (disable com.apple.powermanagement.darkwakelinger)

Tags: terminal, macos, sleep-wake, pmset

From terminal I see that PreventUserIdleSystemSleep assertion takes 15 second before actually sleep. Is there any way to eliminate it, or at least set delay to 0/1 sec?

2017-06-09 23:36:15 +0500 Notification          Display is turned off
2017-06-09 23:36:15 +0500 Assertions            PID 603(AddressBookSourceSync) Summary PreventUserIdleSystemSleep "Address Book Source Sync" 00:00:07  id:0x0x100000185 [System: PrevIdle]
2017-06-09 23:36:15 +0500 Assertions            Kernel Idle sleep preventers: -None-
2017-06-09 23:36:15 +0500 Assertions            PID 52(powerd) Created **InternalPreventSleep "com.apple.powermanagement.darkwakelinger" 00:00:00**  id:0x0xd0000018a [System: PrevIdle SRPrevSleep kCPU]
2017-06-09 23:36:20 +0500 Assertions            Kernel Idle sleep preventers: IODisplayWrangler
2017-06-09 23:36:20 +0500 Notification          Display is turned on
2017-06-09 23:36:30 +0500 Assertions            PID 52(powerd) **TimedOut InternalPreventSleep "com.apple.powermanagement.darkwakelinger" 00:00:15**  id:0x0xd0000018a [System: PrevIdle SRPrevSleep kCPU]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an (apparently undocumented) option in pmset to adjust the "dark wake linger" interval.

```
sudo pmset dwlinterval <seconds>
```

However, I would recommend against changing the default without a good reason.